# Редирект без смены URL с поддомена на раздел другого сайта.

Tags: редирект

Необходимо реализовать редирект со страницы http://en.mcsite.ua/ на страницу https://mcsite.ua/longpage.html, при этом в адресной строке должен остаться адрес http://en.mcsite.ua/. Возможно ли это? Какая конструкция редиректа в htaccess решает эту задачу?

Comment: Уверен, что такое невозможно. Вам сервер скажет браузеру редирект на указанный адрес, тот загрузит его. Адресная строка поменяется.

Comment: Встретил в сети миллион похожих запросов, но точное решение не удалось найти. Кажется, что все-таки возможно, т.к. существует же скрытый редирект с одного домена на другой, когда просто загружается iframe на всю ширину страницы и адрес не меняется.

Comment: Спасибо что прокомментировали, это интересная информация :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainA.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://DomainB.com/PathToPageHere [P]
```

Comment: Подскажите, какие директивы при этом должны быть включены в htaccess?
Сейчас файл выглядит так:

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.mcsite.ua RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mcsite.ua/longpage.html [P]

Получаю 500 ошибку.

Comment: вы пробовали то что я написал выше?

Comment: Да, получаю 404 ошибку сейчас. 
Весь htaccess выглядит так: http://joxi.ru/nAykERBcYk5WEm

Comment: посмотри логи на какую страничку ругается на перенаправленную страничку?

Comment: Лог - [unique_id Wz37qHPhTO0zDAMy0rh10QAAARg] /home/cultures/mcsite.ua/en/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters, referer http://en.mcsite.ua/

Comment: Получается, ругается на поддомен, с которого происходит перенаправление.